# How to connect remote PC with known credentials (IP,Username and password) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, api, visual-studio-2019, remote-access, rdp

I have been trying to establish connection between one central PC and several PCs located at remote space(All connected through LAN network) with windows form(VB.NET) but couldn't succeed. I searched for solution on internet but most of them are in C# and I am not familiar with the C# language.

**I tried below option with different controls**

```
Private Declare Function WNetAddConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetAddConnection2A" (ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer

Private Declare Function WNetCancelConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetCancelConnection2A" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal fForce As Integer) As Integer

Private Structure NETRESOURCE

    Public dwType As Long
    Public lpRemoteName As String

End Structure

Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK = &H1
Private Sub ConnectPC()

    Dim networkResource As New NETRESOURCE()
    Dim lon As Long

    With networkResource

        .dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
        .lpRemoteName = "\\192.168.1.1"

    End With

    lon = WNetAddConnection2(networkResource, "123", "Admin", 0)

    If lon <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Connect" & lon)
    Else
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If


    lon = WNetCancelConnection2("\\192.168.1.1", 0, 1)

    If lon <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Connect" & lon)
    Else
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If

End Sub
```

While trying above code I am getting **Error:487 while connecting and Error:2250 while disconnecting**

Tried Another code with **Remote Desktop Protocol** but couldn't succeed.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        rdpView.Server = "192.168.1.1"
        rdpView.UserName = "Admin"

        Dim isSecured As IMsTscNonScriptable =
           DirectCast(rdpView.GetOcx(), IMsTscNonScriptable)

        isSecured.ClearTextPassword = "123"

        rdpView.Connect()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Connect", "Cannot Connect to: " _
           + "Admin " + ex.Message,
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try
End Sub
```

** All I want is to make connection with information in hand.Can anybody direct me to find the solution? Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: /connecting a network drive is very different to rdp. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to copy one text file from remote computer(with known credential) to my computer but for that I have to establish connection with remote PC. So I just wan to know is there a way to connect remote PC with single click? because once connection is establish I can carry out my operation easily.@CaiusJard

Comment: if youre looking for the absolute esiest way, issue a `net use` command to map a network drive then copy the file like normal